# SQLITE with special character in the json path

Tags: sqlite

I have a column in sqlite which stores a column with json files and the the key of the json can contain any unicode characters. I have a query to calculate the cardinality of the specific key.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(dimensions, '$.*abc')))from `definition`
```

the name is *abc which contains a special character * and used in the json path to the value of the json. the query returns nothing.

In order to read special characters like `*`, the json path is double-quoted and the above query becomes

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(dimensions, '$."*abc"')))from `definition`
```

Now I am able to read json path with `*` but unable to read json path containing a double quote, for example

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(dimensions, '$."a"bc"')))from `definition`
```

I tried to escape the double quotes in the json path with backslash or one additional double quote but it's not working. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually don't need quotes around the object key name. The double quote in the name of that second one one will need to be escaped, though:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test(data TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{"*abc":1,"foo\"bar":2}');
sqlite> SELECT json_extract(data, '$.*abc') FROM test;
json_extract(data, '$.*abc')
----------------------------
1                           
sqlite> SELECT json_extract(data, '$.foo\"bar') FROM test;
json_extract(data, '$.foo\"bar')
--------------------------------
2
```

It's not in [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html), but after looking at the source code, the path string parsing behavior for object keys is:

When encountering a `.`, if the next character is a double quote, read up to the next double quote and use the enclosed text as the name. Otherwise, read up to the next `.` or `[` (Or end of string) and use that as the name. There's no parsing of any JSON string escape sequences or anything else fancy in it.

So the only time you really *need* the quotes is if the key has a `.` or `[` in it. `'$."$.abc"'` for example. It's harmless to use them unless the name has a double quote, though.

Comment: Looking at the source, if the first character after a period in a path fragment is a double quote, the next double quote is used as the end of the key name string (Hence `'$."*abc"'` working). There's no checks for any escaping. There's also none in the path where the first character is something else, so the backslash in the above is needed somewhere else, because it doesn't work without.

Comment: Oh, I bet the backslash before the quote is stored literally in the key string in the object, instead of only being added on rendering into text.

Comment: thanks. two questions:
1.I asked a question about similar usage in mysql and it does need double quotes to make things work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67993770/mysql-with-special-character-in-the-json-path. do u know if sqlite interpret the json path in a different way from your opinion?



2.the solution seems not working with json path `$.abc` and the query is `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (JSON_EXTRACT(dimensions, '$.$.abc'))) `definition`
`. I guess double quotes are needed in this case?

Comment: @dashenswen MySQL and Sqlite are two different products; just because one works one way doesn't mean the other does the same. And it looks like the path string parser, if it sees a period not followed by a quote, reads until the next period or `[`. So that one should be `'$."$.abc"'`, yeah. (This quote stuff doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, annoyingly enough.)

Comment: yeah I agree.. I tried `a.ghi` as well and it suffers the same problem without double quote

Comment: I fleshed out the answer a bit more.